# show/hide div on select change

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show/hide a div element on select change depending on values which is working fine but problem is i am using multiple select box on single page and on change all values show hide at same time  .
For that I do this:

```
    jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.selector').change(function(){
    jQuery('.inv').hide();
    jQuery('.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

[image: If you see in screenshot i have 3 options vps-1, vps-2, vps-3 on click of select i want to change only that box value]

What I'm doing wrong?  please help

Comment: What exactly does your HTML look like? Where is the select and where are the items you want to hide and show. The screenshot of your application doesn't help at all. We need to see the code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery('.selector').closest( ".inv" ).hide(); as jQuery('.inv').hide(); will find everything with that class on it and hide it hence whats happening